# Call Oracle function with Hibernate with object type parameter

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an oracle function that I want to execute with hibernate.

Declaration:

```
Function Compute 
(
     p_RecordIn             in t_RecordType
) 
return t_RecordType;
```

The t_RecordType is a row-type declaration, i.e. it contains all the columns (150) of a table.

I tried calling the function via NativeQuery:

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

Session sess = em.unwrap(Session.class);
NativeQuery<?> query = sess.createNativeQuery("BEGIN :l_Erg_Rec \\:=  Compute( p_RecordIn => :l_Input_Rec ); END;");
query.setParameter("l_Input_Rec", input);
query.setParameter("l_Erg_Rec", result);

return (MyResult) query.list().get(0);
```

My pojo input class looks like this:

```
@Data
public class RecordIn implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

...
}
```

Where I just map pojo fields to column names.

I cannot modify the function.

I receive this error:

```
oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 14:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'Compute'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Edit: Updated my answer. Instead of Select-Statement I did a function call.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This answer focuses on the issues within the Oracle code; once you have addressed those issues then you can get the Java code working.*

> The `t_RecordType` is a row-type declaration, i.e. it contains all the columns (150) of a table.

A `RECORD` is a PL/SQL data structure that is valid in the PL/SQL scope but not in the SQL scope. (And, even though it is not shown, you have probably declared it in a PL/SQL scope within a package).

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE package_name IS
  SUBTYPE t_RecordType IS DUAL%ROWTYPE;

  FUNCTION compute(
    p_RecordIn IN t_RecordType
  ) RETURN t_recordType;
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY package_name IS
  FUNCTION compute(
    p_RecordIn IN t_RecordType
  ) RETURN t_recordType
  IS
  BEGIN
    return p_RecordIn;
  END;
END;
/
```

Therefore, if you want to use the function `compute` you will need to use it in PL/SQL:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_rec_i package_name.t_RecordType;
  v_rec_o package_name.t_RecordType;
BEGIN
  v_rec_i.dummy := 'X';
  v_rec_o := Package_Name.Compute( p_RecordIn => v_rec_i );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_rec_o.dummy);
END;
/
```

Which outputs `X`.

or using bind variables:

```sql
BEGIN
  :l_output_rec := Package_Name.Compute( p_RecordIn => :l_input_rec );
END;
```

Rather than in an SQL `SELECT` statement.

```sql
SELECT Package_Name.Compute( p_RecordIn => package_name.t_RecordType('X') ).dummy
FROM   dual
```

Which outputs the exception:

> ```
> ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'T_RECORDTYPE'
> ```

---

If you want to use something similar in an SQL scope then you should create an `OBJECT` type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE t_ObjectType IS OBJECT(
  dummy VARCHAR2(10)
);
```

then you can use it in the function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION compute(
  p_ObjectIn IN t_ObjectType
) RETURN t_ObjectType
IS
BEGIN
  return p_ObjectIn;
END;
/
```

and in the query:

```sql
SELECT Compute( p_ObjectIn => t_ObjectType('X') ) from dual
```

or, if you want the value:

```sql
SELECT Compute( p_ObjectIn => t_ObjectType('X') ).dummy from dual
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LL8KnOLq)

Comment: If I understand you correct, I replace the select with the following code and it should work? ```BEGIN
  :l_output_rec := Package_Name.Compute( p_RecordIn => :l_input_rec );
END;```

Comment: @Prophet Assuming that your function is defined in a package then, from the Oracle side it should work. I do not use hibernate and have not checked your Java code so I don't know if binding to a PL/SQL record type will work or not (okay, I know it won't work straight off because you've gone from one input bind parameter to one input and one output bind parameter but once you fix that then I can't comment on whether it will work or what needs fixing if it doesn't).

Comment: I updated my answer. There is now another error.